# Compatibility between .NET Framework 4.7 WebForms and .NET Core 3.1(class library)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, reference

everyone.
We are wondering if it exists the possibility of mixing both .NET Framework and .NET Core(as a class library) in the same project/solution.

We have an old .NET Framework 4.7.2 app based on WebForms (written in VB.NET). Our goal is to isolate and remake the data layer and use Entity Framework Core with the new data access layer(written in C#). The initial idea was making a .NET Core library with all the entities and models, and then connect to the .NET framework project. We don't know if this is possible, and if it is, we don`t know what kind of configurations we have to make to make it work.

We are open to other solutions (maybe using another kind of project and not a library, or maybe using a .NET Framework library with EF Core, instead a .NET Core library). Any ideas are welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class library project based on `.Net Standard` but Microsoft has discontinued the version for `.Net Framework` considering it is going to be a legancy framework. Take a look the table bellow for compatibility version:

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/net-standard